# SSRS 2016 compatible with SQL Server 2014 db server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i have a sql server 2014 and few databases in it,
Can i setup and install ssrs 2016 and use the databases on sql server 2014 for making few reports?
The reason for thinking so is just found that ssrs 2016 report rendering engine have some advantages like it follows html5 rendering standards

So can some one guide on this

Comment: This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use SQL Server 2014 database as either a host for the report server catalog AND/OR as a source for report data. They are cross compatible back to SQL 2008 for hosting and forever for data.